# How to put batch code in one line command

Tags: cmd

I'm newbie with command line and batch files.
I have a task to make a code which checks the txt-file for presence of specific line. If the line doesn't exist in the file the code is supposed to add this specific line. The problem is that I have to make this code in one line because it will be used in software which GUI can keep and execute only one command line but not batch file.
Here what I have:

1. File `1.txt` with lines:

```
ab cde
1 23
456
```

2. My command line:

```
set /a f=3 & set "My_str=f gh" & (for /f "delims=" %x in (1.txt) do if "%My_str%"=="%x" set /a f=1 ) & ( if !f! lss 2 call echo %My_str%>>1.txt)
```

So I use flag `f` to indicate the existence of line `f gh` in my txt-file. Flag value `f=3` means the line doesn't exist and it needs to be added. If the line exist the flag will have value `f=1` and condition `(!f! lss 2)` will not trigger adding the line.
It looks like `if !f! lss 2` doesn't work how I want and my command just add every time the line `f gh` although it already exist in the file (e.g. after previous executions in other cmd windows before).
Thanks.

Comment: As you're using `!f! `, does that mean that the command is executed with delayed expansion on ?

Comment: It might be better to give the inflexible GUI program a line that calls a .bat or .ps1 script. The script file can then be written on multiple lines so that it is readable and maintainable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your command is run with delayed expansion ON (`cmd /V:ON`), it seems that your `!f!` flag check sould be then `IF NOT !f! lss 2 call echo ...` or, as `!f!` here is a **flag**, `IF NOT !f! == 1 call echo ...`. The `if !f! lss 2 call ..` means "if `!f!` is lower than 2" and these will trigger the add if `!f!` is 1. I also guess you may need to activate delayed expansion.

You should then force it with :

```
cmd /V:ON /C "set /a f=3 & set "My_str=f gh" & (for /f "delims=" %x in (1.txt) do if "%My_str%"=="%x" set /a f=1 ) & ( if NOT !f! lss 2 call echo %My_str%>>1.txt)"
```

Comment: Delayed expansion must also be applied to `!My_str!`, which allows to avoid `call echo`…

Comment: Thank you! I tried to add in the beginning `Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion &` to activate delayed expansion, but I didn't get how it works (I guess it didn't work).
Now I know how to activate it correctly

Comment: @aschipfl You're right, it would be better to avoid call. As the main point of the answer was about what was wrong with the logical test and how to trigger the delayed expansion in that case, it seems to me out of the scope of the question. For me, using FINDSTR and its exit status  code would be even better that the script, but OP needs first to understand what was wrong in its construct and what to do to achieve its initial goal.

Answer (score 1):

Why so complicated? Why not using a variable that simply indicates presence of the line string just by being defined or not?

```
set "F=" & (for /F "delims=" %X in (1.txt) do if "%X"=="f gh" set "F=#") & if not defined F >>1.txt echo/f gh
```

Or not using `for /F` but [`findstr`](https://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) instead:

```
> nul findstr /X /C:"f gh" 1.txt || >>1.txt echo/f gh
```

Comment: Nice! Thank you. I think first one has to be `if NOT defined F`. Right? 
I made it so complicated because I am not a programmer actually :)

Comment: You're welcome! Yes, of course, it should read `if not defined F`. Please read: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)